# Use of "petri dish" as metaphor in non-scientific context

Tags: word-usage

Can the word *petri dish* be used as a metaphor in a non-scientific context?

Comment: Yes. You just did.

Comment: Note that it is Petri dish (with a capital P). It's named after a bacteriologist.

Comment: @JLG: _[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/petri%2Bdish?region=us&q=petri+dish)_ has it lower-case.

Comment: @Callithumpian. Ok. But in *Dorland's Medical Dictionary* and *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary* it is still a cap P.

Comment: At all answerers so far: Any technical/ special term could be used in a metaphorical sense in general English. That is therefore, to be excluded from the options for this question. Can we use it literally? "Please pass the petri dish," so to say.

Comment: @Mark No OP didn't use it metaphorically.

Comment: @Kris when the question was first written it did not include the words "as a metaphor". So my subsequent comment looks moronic :) Good thing I didn't make it an answer!

Comment: So it is here. I'll call it the first-mover advantage ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it can!

> The city was a petri dish for crime.

Answer (score 6):

*Petri dish* is used metaphorically quite often. Here are a few examples from a quick search of recent article titles:

> [Is Facebook the Petri Dish of Jealousy in Your Love Life? What “Cyberpsychology” Says](http://bigthink.com/ideas/is-facebook-the-petri-dish-of-jealousy-in-your-love-life-what-cyberpsychology-says)
>
> [The United States: A Petri Dish of Liberal Democracy](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xggd4n_the-united-states-a-petri-dish-of-liberal-democracy_news)
>
> [The Internet is the petri-dish of humanity. We can't control what grows in it, but we don't have to watch either.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/show/236469)
>
> [Wireless hotspots: petri dish of wireless security](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1132501)

Answer (score 4):

Of course petri dish **can** be used as a metaphor.  I think what you meant to ask was ***Is*** petri dish used as a metaphor in non-scientific contexts?  And the answer is: yes.

Here's an example from [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/democracyinamerica/2011/04/washingtons_predicament), April 2011:

> This grim scenario, however, was only averted by a deal that treated *[Washington]* DC as a sort of **petri dish** for House Republicans’ social experiment.

I.e. a petri dish is a place where (or upon which) experiments are conducted.

Comment: It's where microbes grow, not quite where you 'conduct experiments.'

Comment: @Kris That's the literal meaning, but I was talking about the metaphorical meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Petri dish can be used as a metaphor, but it might not be the best metaphor for social-science contexts. Remember that bacteria do not have agency like humans. So saying, for example, that the city is a Peti dish for the social sciences risks de-humanizing the subjects of social science research. This might not bother you, and it might be appropriate for your piece. But make sure you think of how this metaphor *could* be *mis*interpreted.