# Why does the term Petri Dishes appear so regularly in political discourse nowadays?

Tags: science, politics, social-media

On three occasions on Twitter and other social media platforms, the term "Petri Dishes" appears in a non-scientific context. Is this just a recent fad? It appears to be in the lexicon of many of our more prolific commentators and journalists.

Comment: This would probably be a better question over on the [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is not new. See the answers to https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66311/42179

Comment: Mainly because the people using the term don't know what it means.

Comment: Please give at least two full quotes and links where this is used.

Comment: If one consults Urban Dictionary, then the correlation with politics and politicians may be more clear...